# How to add Cursor in Website using css?

Tags: html, css, cursor, stylesheet, custom-cursor

I want to add Custom set of cursor on my website. 
How can i add a set of Cursors in Website using css/html/js ?
So , Default mouse pointer is different, when i hover hyperlink its diff,,.. n so on.
I need help with css code.
I have the Set of Pointers including both `.ani` & `.cur` required for my site.
I have already tried :-

These codes in my `style.css`

```
body, a:hover {cursor: url(cursor/blue.cur), progress !important;}
```

Still no luck !
I have a master page and what I want is to assign a default custom cursor to the page and have all links use another custom cursor

Is this possible?

Comment: You may want to read up on how to use the CSS cursor property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Comment: body {cursor: URL(imageFileUrl);}
i tried this in my main style.css but it didnt worked.

Answer (score 0):

With css you can do that:

```
body {cursor: URL(imageFileUrl);}
```

If you need more information [read this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp).

**EDIT:** This worked for me: `<body style="cursor: url('cursor.jpg'), default">`

The imagen that I've used is a jpg 32x32.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.cursor = "url('cursor/blue.cur'), auto";
</script>
```

this must work IE 6+

Comment: thnx alot. it work gud, i wanna ask u when i hover a hyperlink can it be changed to red.cur ?